# Why can't I bind an lvalue-reference to an rvalue while a concept can?

Tags: c++, standards, c++20, rvalue-reference, c++-concepts

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
concept IsWritable = requires(T& obj)
{
    obj = 0;
};

template<typename T>
void f(T&)
{}

int main()
{
    static_assert(IsWritable<int&&>); // ok
    
    int n = 0;
    f(std::move(n)); // error
}
```

GCC error message:

```
error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'int&' to an rvalue of type 
       'std::remove_reference<int&>::type' {aka 'int'}
```

Why can't I bind an lvalue-reference to an rvalue while a concept can?

Comment: And where is the binding of an lvalue reference to rvalue in a concept?

Comment: Strictly speaking, a concept's requires expression cannot have the binding of an lvalue reference to an rvalue, because it's compile-time evaluation. I just wonder: why does the C++20 standard allow the counter-intuitive behavior?

Comment: If `T` is `int&&`, then what is the type of `int&& &`? Note that here is not a universal reference.

Comment: `int&& &` is `int&` and you can assign `0` to an `int&` value. What is the problem?

Comment: @xmllmx, the type of `int&& &` is `int&` because reference collapsing appies to references, not only to universal references.

Comment: If so, why `f(std::move(n))` doesn't work likewise?

Comment: @xmllmx, because you're binding an rvalue to a non-`const` reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&)
{}
```

the line

```
    f(std::move(n)); // error
```

must error, because you're trying to pass an rvalue argument, `std::move(n)`, to a lvalue reference parameter, `T&`.

As regards the concept, notice that there's no argument-parameter pair *on the value level*. And it's on the *value level* that talking about rvalue/lvalue-ness makes sense (after all, those are called [value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)).

There's an argument-parameter pair on the type level, though: you're explicitly passing the `int&&` *template argument* to `IsWritable`'s *template argument* `T`, so the `T&` will be `int&& &`, which is `int&`, because normal reference collpasing applies (it doesn't just apply to universal references).